# Ubuntu 19.04 slows down under heavy graphics card load [RTX 2070]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I encountered a performance issue when my video card is under heavy load.

My system consists of the following components:

- MSI MPG X570 Gaming Edge Wifi (Bios Version: 7C37v12; AGESA: 1.0.0.3a)
- AMD Ryzen 3700x (no overclocking)
- AORUS GeForce RTX ™ 2070 XTREME 8G
- Cosair Ripjaw V Dual (16GB) [XMP Profile enabled in bios for 3200MHz support] - problem also occurs without

On the SSD is Ubuntu 19.04 freshly installed, but with "old" /home directory from another HDD.
The graphics driver is from the Ubuntu repository (nvidia-driver-430.40)

Now to the following problem:

Every time the graphics card runs under load, the whole system becomes extremely slow and hardly reacts. At first I noticed this in some Linux games, after that I tested it all with a benchmark tool (https://benchmark.unigine.com/superposition). Under low graphics settings (720p, shader low, etc.), everything runs very smoothly and without problems. However, if I increase the quality, then colorful graphics glitches and after a short time, the system is extremely slow. The mouse freezes on and off and the sound from the benchmark tool "hangs" occasionally. I have to reset the computer in this state.

Note: The GPU fans turn off or on, depending on the load. Even if I can stop the benchmark test, the graphics card will not come to rest even after 10 minutes and the fans will turn permanently. At this time, no application is running in the background, which causes a load on the graphics card.
The card specs are 1815MHz max. clock speed, but the benchmark tool show 1915 MHz

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? Does the driver die, or is it possibly related to the bios version and the current Ryzen problem?

**Update:**

I didn't overclock the card, but it took a look into throttling. I downloaded GreenWithEnvy and made some tests with GPU clock throttling (-100MHz) but it doesn't solve the issue. Furthermore I figured out some interesting things: I downloaded a Blender benchmark file and the graphics card can render it over 11 mins on full speed (1920MHz) without any issue. Looks like it is a software issue because GPU and VRAM are working as expected.

**Update 2019-09-22:**

I made same benchmark test under Ubuntu 19.10 with Nvidia 435.21 driver with same result, it looks like the driver crashes by using OpenGL.
After that I updated my bios to 7C37v14; AGESA: 1.0.0.3abba.
In addition, I run MemtestG80 by 7000MiB blocks to exclude VRAM issues. After 30 iterations I got zero errors.
Finally, the issue still persists. :(

**Update 2019-10-05:**

I replaced the card with a new Gigabyte RTX 2070 Super Gaming OC. Benchmark runs without any graphic glitches under same system. I guess the other card was broken and I sent it back to the vendor.

Comment: Total shot in the dark here: 'colorful graphics glitches' indicate artifacting to me (i.e. bad memory, too high overclock). Since you don't mention that you overclocked the card, could it be that the card has a hardware problem. At our office, we just had to send back a 2080Ti because it had some crazy hardware problem (could only do 1/4 of the framerates, would frequently crash programs). The new one works flawless. Think you could test the card in another machine, possibly a Windows one?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it with a Windows system.

Comment: If you have a spare HDD kicking around, you could [download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10ISO) and do a temporary install on it in your system (I would disconnect any drives are already in your system, so that Windows doesn't mess with them). You would need a flash drive to flash the ISO to as well. This could give you a more definite answer whether it's a driver issue (if it works in Windows) or if it is a hardware issue (if it doesn't work in Windows either).

Comment: Please see my update. I made some tests with Blender benchmark files without any issue. It let me doubt that it is an hardware issue but who knows. :(

Comment: Blender 2.8 with Cycles set to CUDA?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 2.8, cycles and cuda.